# Approach to storing and retrieving time when having multiple systems talking to each other

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

Consider this scenario with two applications whose data is synced

Application 1 | Application 2

Data from application1 is inserted/updated into application2 based on last modified date of records.

How can we make sure that the last modified date is not dependent on time zones.

Comment: Use `GETUTCDATE()` ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [rowversion](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776(v=sql.110).aspx) column in both applications. To decide what to sync you can have a query or a `merge` statement and in the `where` clause you can compare the  rows `table1.RowVersion > table2.RowVersion`. (table1 is from application1 and table2 is from application2)

Answer (score 0):

This might help: [ToUniversalTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime.aspx)

Convert the times to universal times, these take into account the time zone, daylight savings, etc. If you convert both times before adding the records, you should be able to get the correct last modified date.